# Notepad++ want to use RegEx to seek minimum-length strings

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Only been using Notepad++ v 5.92 for a few weeks, and RegEx for a few hours (!!)
I want to use Find & Replace for UPPERCASE strings of a minimum length to change them to "Title Case" or "Sentence case".

I found patterns in an online tutorial for the string

```
([A-Z])
```

Pattern for length of string
`\{5,50\}`
How do I combine this syntax in Notepad++ to get a working find instead of "not found" message?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ doesn't [support `{x,y}` operator](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators). Even if it did - you cannot use it to replace the  uppercase with lowercase/titlecase strings.

Comment: ah, well. I would have been using my faithful AutoHotkey script to do the actual case-changing, it is the string-selection that I'm trying to get my hands on.  Thanks for your time.